# Would there be any difference or performance difference between these 2 web page load method - c# - html agility pack

Tags: c#, wpf, web-crawler, html-agility-pack, dom

Currently i am using C# 4.0 and htmlagilitypack 1.4.0 for downloading webpages and extracting information.

It is possible to download webpages with the way below by using htmlagilitypack

```
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument myDoc = hw.Load("URL");
```

But you are not able to set encoding with this way. So for be able to set encoding the method below is working.

```
        HtmlDocument  myDoc=new HtmlDocument();         
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text).GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9")); //put your encoding            
        myDoc.Load(reader);
```

But i wonder would there be any difference or performance difference between these 2 methods. What would be Advantageous and disadvantageous of these 2 methods. Thank you.

C# 4.0 , wpf , htmlagilitpack , crawl page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't difference between the two ways. `HtmlWeb.Load(string url)` internally calls `HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader)` as the following HtmlWeb.Load(string url) call stack, which I used .NET Reflector to see.

```
HtmlWeb.Load(string url)
----> HtmlDocument.Load(string url, Encoding encoding(=this.OverrideEncoding))
----> HtmlDocument.Load(TextReader reader)
```

This tells you can use HtmlWeb.OverrideEncoding property to set a encoding and if you do not set a encoding and just call HtmlWeb.Load(string url), `HtmlWeb.Load(string url)` will call `HtmlDocument.DetectEncodingAndLoad(string path, bool detectEncoding(=true))`.